# Travelling to the UK while settlement visa is in appeal

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, children, canadian-citizens

I am a Canadian married to a Scot. I recently received my UK settlement visa but my 8-year-old child was refused on the basis that we did not provide enough evidence of that I had sole responsibility (which I have).

We have submitted what we believe should prove sole responsibility through appeal and are waiting.

We would like to visit my husband in the UK. Can we do while my son's visa is in appeal? Canadians don't need a visa to travel to UK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coming for a visit shouldn't be a problem, although there is a chance of it not going so well due to the failed application. And while Canadians do not need to apply for a visa before coming to the UK, you may have to pass the same immigration checks so make sure to bring all the supporting documents you would usually put forth with a visitors visa application.

And unless you are in a rush, I would suggest making this trip a lot easier for you, and your eight years old, by applying for visitors visa before flying. This way any potential immigration issues will be already dealt with, and after the flight, you will pretty much sail through the border.

Comment: My edit was just to make the 'do no' to do not